# Max & Distinct based on several field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on the raw data below and expected result, I need help on how to come up with the correct query.

Basically, I need that data based on max(ID), however, do note that RATING and TYPE field could be different hence Group By wouldn't work.

Thank you.

[image: Raw Data & Expected Result]

Comment: It is great to provide sample data and expected output, but please do not provide them as pictures. Let this be copy'n'pasteable. Best would be a test scenarion with `CREATE TABLE #test ...` or `DECLARE @test TABLE( ...` with your test values inserted - or a [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: hi @Shnugo noted, would keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the highest id for each `NumId`.  You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by NumId order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where t.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if no other row has the same NumTitle but a higher ID value:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.NumTitle = t1.NumTitle
                    and t2.ID > t1.ID)
```

Or, `JOIN` version:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select NumTitle, MAX(ID) from tablename group by NumTitle) t2
    on t2.NumTitle = t1.NumTitle and t2.ID = t1.ID
```